# check if JSON objects property contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, foreach

I'm using a movie database api that searches for films and pulling data through, each film object has a property called poster_path, I am accessing this through a variable (baseImgURL) and this works. e.g 
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg

However some films don't have images and such have "null" in their poster_path, I'm trying to do an if statement that checks if the poster_path value contains "null" and if it does replace the image with a local file image.

At the moment it's currently replacing all images with the local file image, what would be the best approach for this? Should I use a forEach loop?

```
request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    data.results.forEach(film=> {     
...

var baseImgURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + film.poster_path;

var filmImage = document.createElement("img");
filmImage.src = baseImgURL;

if(filmImage.src.indexOf("null")){
   filmImage.src = "/img/imagenotavailable.png";
}
```

Comment: First I don't think it actually contains the literal string value of "null", secondly you would have to investigate and research the difference between forEach, and other loops and use the one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!!filmImage.src` (strict null-type checking) instead of `filmImage.src.indexOf("null")` since the JSON string is parsed to an object.